# SpringBoot 1 vs 2 and Spring Oauth2- Password Grant and Client Secret

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

Does anybody know how the versioning in SpringBoot and Spring Oauth2 works?
When I change the versions of SpringBoot and Spring Oauth2 I go from getting valid access and refresh tokens to an "unauthorized" error . I am using spring-boot-starter-parent.
**I ran some tests and its the Spring Boot version; when I change the version from 1.*.* to 2.*.* "/oauth/token" will not get hit any more**.
Here is the config of the Autherization Server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends 
AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws 
Exception {
configurer
    .inMemory()
    .withClient(CLIENT_ID)
    //.secret("secret")
    .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, REFRESH_TOKEN)
    .redirectUris("http://localhost:8080/")
    .scopes(SCOPE_READ)
    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS).
    refreshTokenValiditySeconds(REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
    }
    ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go from SpringBoot 1 to 2,

- you will have to add a client secret in order for the authorization server to work. This is just how Spring Boot works.
- If you are using a client secret in Spring Boot 1, you dont need to pass the hash but in Spring Boot 2 you will need to do that:

  ```
  inMemory()
  .withClient(CLIENT_ID)
  .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("secret"))
  ```